# What is the difference between getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, ...) and clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID,...) in Linux?

Tags: linux, multithreading, real-time

The question pretty much says it all.  According to the man page for `getrusage()`, it returns:

```
           struct timeval ru_utime; /* user CPU time used */
           struct timeval ru_stime; /* system CPU time used */
```

According to the man page for `clock_gettime()`, it returns:

```
   CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID (since Linux 2.6.12)
          Thread-specific CPU-time clock.
```

So, how does (thread specific) "user/system CPU time used" differ from a thread-specific CPU-time clock?

Obviously, I'm asking because I see a difference between the two in an application I have ported to Linux (from a custom RTOS).  That application has an internal profiling capability implemented with `tick()` and `tock()` functions.  As I have been digging into this, I have degenerated one part of my application to be:

```
tick()
// code commented out
tock()
```

The `tick()` function records the time at which it was run, the `tock()` function records the time at which it was run, computes the delta between the two, and reports that delta.  When I implement `tick()` and `tock()` using `getrusage()`, I get mostly 0's out, and occasionally 1000us or 10000us values (according to whether I have configured my kernel for 1kHz or 100Hz operation).  When I implement `tick()` & `tock()` using `clock_gettime()`, I get values centered about 13us (with bizarre excursions to 75us or 100us occasionally, but I'll deal with later).

I have tried enabling high res timers in the kernel and various combinations of `VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING` and/or `VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN`.  The only effect I have seen is that the non-zero values reported by `getrusage()` change from 1000us to a range of higher precision values centered about 1000us.

I finally switched to using `clock_gettime()` and have much more believable results, but I am left wondering why the two system calls exist, and why they behave so differently.  So I figured I should ask some experts.

Comment: Have you compared results to `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`?

Comment: `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is global, not thread-specific.  I am looking for an elapsed time timer specific to my thread.

Comment: I was wondering if there were significant differences between `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` and `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID`.  In other words, if they actually measured different things.  Using `strace` might also shed some light on the differences between the calls.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, …) and
>   clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID,…) in Linux?

`clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, …)` ultimately calls [`task_sched_runtime(p)`](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.4/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L2819), which takes the accounted runtime from `p->se.sum_exec_runtime`, where `struct task_struct *p` is `current`.

`getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, …)` calls `task_cputime_adjusted(current, &utime, &stime)`, for which two definitions [[a]](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.4/source/kernel/sched/cputime.c#L442), [[b]](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.4/source/kernel/sched/cputime.c#L647) exist; which of them is used depends on the Linux kernel configuration item [CONFIG_VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_NATIVE](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_NATIVE.html):

> Select this option to enable more accurate task and CPU time
>   accounting.

Now we would need to know whether this option is selected in your kernel. Anyway, both cases look different from the method used by `clock_gettime()`.

That said, I can't reproduce your findings (I get nearly the same numbers from both system calls). An example program could help further.

> So I figured I should ask some experts.

I think you'd find the real experts on a Linux kernel mailing list.